# how to remember multiple indexes in a buffer to later access them for modification one by one...keeping optimization in mind

Tags: c, buffer

i have a scenario where i have to set few records with field values to a constant and then later access them one by one sequentially .
The records can be random records.
I dont want to use link list as it will be costly and don't want to traverse the whole buffer.
please give me some idea to do that.

Comment: random guess - variables?

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Did you try using a link list and profile it afterwards, or are you just assuming that it will be too expensive in runtime overhead?

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin proposal seems to be the only better alternative to linked list; an array of pointer over the record ( or an array of struct defining record field )... This question is quite vague...

Comment: actually the number of records are very large...so link lists  would not be an option for me. Rather i want use some efficient sorting mechanism.

Comment: Unless "very large" is many millions of records, that restriction makes no sense. And for linked lists a well-written mergesort can't be beat. With an array you have much more severe space problems (how large to make it? if it turns out too small, need to reallocate... need at _least_ twice as much space in the meantime, and if you request say 1, then 2, 4, 8, ... the space left free from the first allocations won't be reclaimable easily).

Comment: Oh, and "keep optimizations in mind" is the disease known as premature optimization. It leads to impossible to understand code, serious bugs, bad performance, and premature programmer baldness by constant hair-pulling. Severe cases of stomach ulcer have also been reported.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with linked lists -- just I'd suggest using two of them. Keep your original list untouched and modify only the other. Then at the stage of processing the original list sequentially, merge in the sorted _change list_. BTW. "Keep optimization in mind" is not premature optimization but the key to productive programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "set few records with field values to a constant" is this like a key to the record?  And then "later access them one by one" - is this to recall them with some key?  "one-by-one sequentially" and "don't want to traverse the whole buffer" seems to conflict, as sequential access sounds a lot like traversal.

But I digress.  If you in fact do have a key (and it's a number), you could use some sort of Hash Table to organize your records.  One basic implementation might be an array of linked lists, where you mod the key down into the array's range, then add it to the list there.  This *might* increase performance assuming you have a good distribution of keys (your records spread across the array well).

Another data structure to look into might be a B-Tree or a binary search tree, which can access nodes in logarithmic time.

However, overall I agree with the commenters that over-optimizing is usually not a good idea.